# Spring Cloud: How to define default fallback for Hystrix in Zuul gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am using Spring Cloud Brixton.M3 and Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE. I am sort of new in this (especially in Spring Cloud). I have created Registry Server (i.e. Eureka instance), Config server and Gateway.
As per my requirement I am intercepting each request hitting the gateway in one of my Filter to extract required information from Header and based upon that I am throwing exception or forwarding / verifying that request using `Feign Client`. Some time hystrix throw `HystrixRuntimeException` when it couldn't reach out to respective services or because of any other issues.

So What I want is:

1. Provide default fallback method for every forwarding request, so that I can read and process it accordingly.
2. Global Exception handling other than `@ControllerAdvice` since I am not providing any custom `@HystrixCommand` and Controller to call services (AOP based solution ?).
3. Is it possible to intercept every failed request and retry them for certain number of times ? Internally it might be happening but can I override this functionality and handle each failed request either because of `TimedOutException` or because of HttpConnectionPool exception ?

**Update**
Is it a good practice to provide own routing in Zuul gateway ? using `@RestController` and `@HystrixCommand` together ? (I think its a bad idea, because over the period of time we will end up with lots of controllers and hence actual use of intelligent routing wouldn't work as expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Netflix/feign/issues/298) for fallbacks with feign. There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/250) for fallbacks with zuul.

Comment: 2nd link says **fallback per route**. does it mean without writing own hystrix command ? I mean a default dynamic fallback for each route ? What I understand so far from **Hystrix Fallback** is that we provide `@HystrixCommand` an argument as `fallbackmethod`. It is not that one right ?

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for tips. I have updated my question though. ;)